# JQuery easyUI tabs are not working with prettyfaces URL Rewriter

Tags: jquery, jsf, jquery-easyui

I am working on a project which is using JQuery easyUI plugin for displaying dynamic tabs.And PrettyFaces for url rewriting .But pretty faces unable to load the css and javascript files.
Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
    function addTab (title, url) {
        if ($('#tt').tabs('exists', title)) {
            $('#tt').tabs('select', title);
        } else {
            var content = '<iframe id="frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="'
                    + url + '" style="width:110%;height:100%;" ></iframe>';
            $('#tt').tabs('add', {
                title : title,
                content : content,
                closable : true,
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am getting below error

```
[17:25:08.081] TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between what happened inside the iframe and what happened in the js code.
I made a small test, here its working. http://jsfiddle.net/pt7j9/1/

**update the test if you want to show us what is not working.**

```
 <div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs" style="width:1500px;height:700px;">

    </div>

function addTab (title, url) {
        if ($('#tt').tabs('exists', title)) {
            $('#tt').tabs('select', title);
        } else {
            var content = '<iframe id="frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="'
                    + url + '" style="width:10%;height:100%;" ></iframe>';
            $('#tt').tabs('add', {
                title : title,
                content : content,
                closable : true,
                fit:true
            });
        }
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    addTab ("test", "http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/");
    });
```